# volley response returns a null value

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am trying to create a simple registration page that passes username, email, and password to php side. 
I checked my php code with a RESTclient(postman) and it works fine. but when I trying to pass the params from android using volley, the response in onResponse returns a null value.
here is the code:

```
Php:

DbOperations.php

<?php
class DbOperations{     
    private $con;
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';
    $db = new DbConnect();
    $this->con = $db->connect();
}   
function createUser($username,$pass,$email){
    $password = md5($pass);
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `android`.`users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?);");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$username,$password,$email);            
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }   
}

registerUser.php

<?php

    if      
    (isset($_POST['username']) and
        isset($_POST['password']) and 
        isset($_POST['email'])
        ){
            $db = new DbOperations();       
            if($db->createUser(
                $_POST['username'],
                $_POST['password'],
                $_POST['email']
            )){
                $response['error'] = "false"; $response['message'] = "user register success";
            }else{
                $response['error'] = "true";
                $response['message'] = "user register failed";
            }
    }else{
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
    }
}else{
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "invalid post request";
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Android:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText etUsername,etEmail,etPassword;
private Button bt;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    etUsername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    etPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pasword);

    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);

    progressDialog =new ProgressDialog(this);

    bt.setOnClickListener(this);

}


private void registerUser(){
        final String email=etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String username=etUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password=etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering..");
    progressDialog.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.URL_REGISTER,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username",username);
            params.put("email",email);
            params.put("password",password);

            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v==bt)
        registerUser();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

first you should check the response.
can you please share the code of php 
in register file after registering the username etc you should print some response there so you would get that response in volley

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name(username,password,email) VALUES('$username','$password','$email')";

```
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

        echo 'successfully registered';

}
```

after changing this code check the response , then you would get successfully registered so in the java compare response then toast

Comment: I had checked the php code using postman.it works fine.( the json returns the message key). please check the question.i have added the php code also

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you have done this or not,just try like following

Try define a empty array in the first place like so :

```
$response = array(); <--add this line,create an empty array 1st..then only can echo out

 if      
    (isset($_POST['username']) and
        isset($_POST['password']) and 
        isset($_POST['email'])
        ){
            $db = new DbOperations();       
            if($db->createUser(
                $_POST['username'],
                $_POST['password'],
                $_POST['email']
            )){
                $response['error'] = "false"; $response['message'] = "user register success";
            }else{
                $response['error'] = "true";
                $response['message'] = "user register failed";
            }
    }else{
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
    }
}else{
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "invalid post request";
}
echo json_encode($response);
```